# Save 3D view in rendered shading in HQ

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

Is it possible to save the 3D view in the Rendered shading (or render preview) in HQ (defined resolution)? Because when I do Render preview I like the way looks, I like to save it directly, instead of to click the Render button (or F12), since else I must wait again for the same picture.

This question [How to save print-quality screenshots of the 3D view?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5972/how-to-save-print-quality-screenshots-of-the-3d-view) only works for Solid, Texture, Material, Wireframe and Bounding Box, but not for Rendered. Thanks :)

For example (the rendered preview):
[image]
After clicking the 3D view render button:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think the best thing you can do is to take a screenshot, either using external software or via *Window> Save Screenshot*:

[image]

The downside is that you will have to crop out the rest of the interface afterwards as that will also be captured.

Comment: Thanks, but can I make a picture with a defined resolution (properties panel)?

Comment: Not really, the preview really is only intended as a preview.

Comment: What about an OpenGL render?