# Freestyle line is not showing

Tags: freestyle

Im following this tutorial on YT https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZiqrCRqyLzE. But freestyle line does not appears. Freestyle checkbox is ticked, add-ons are ticked (LoopTools, PieMenu Official). I tried it with new fresh blender project, but nothing. Im in Blender 1.78, Win 7 Ultimate x64.

[image]

[image]

Just editing and adding my file since I am doing the same tutorial and having the same problem: [image]

Adding a camera to the scene worked! (I am adding this here since I cannot comment yet) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you use Blender Internal like in tutorial? what are the settings for the freestyle color? What are those objects shown on screenshot, 2 cubes or just planes? Please use [blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) to upload the file

Comment: Regarding the file attached try adding camera object to the scene, for some reason lines render only if it's present (probably a limitation however you won't be able to output image wihtout a camera regardless unless taking screenshot)

Comment: @MrZak this seems to have worked, care to convert your comment into an answer so that it can be accepted?

Comment: @dr.Sybren I'd say answer it, I don't think I can find any info of why it works like that.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the file attached try adding [camera object](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/camera/introduction.html) to the scene, for some reason Freestyle lines render only if it's present.

It's probably a limitation however you won't be able to output an image without a camera regardless unless [taking a screenshot of the preview render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32454/save-3d-view-in-rendered-shading-in-hq) (although in Cycles Freestyle lines will be rendered only in the final aka F12 render so screenshot won't work as well).

Comment: This limitation still seem to be present with Cycles render engine in Blender 2.79 and in 2.80 beta. Freestyle lines do only appear after the final F12 image rendering is completed and not during the preview!

Answer (score 0):

Without having a look at your blend file I can only guess: Try switching the *Logical OR* to *Logical AND* to show crease edges as well as material edges.

Comment: I've tried switching the logical or or logical and, nothing.

Comment: So please consider uploading your blend file to [blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).