# Freestyle Line Set not Showing in Blender 2.79

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Similar problem as in this other post:

[Freestyle line is not showing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88648/freestyle-line-is-not-showing)

Freestyle Line Set should be in Render Layers ( Properties ), but is not Showing in Blender 2.79

Based on Blender 2.79 manual it should be there. Do I need to activate something. I already activated an addon called: FreeStyle Line Style SVG Export, but that didn't help.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/freestyle/parameter_editor/line_set.html#edge-marks

[image]

Comment: How is your question different from that one? Did you try to use answer provided there? How about posting some screenshots of the settings?

Comment: @Mr Zak, thanks for the suggestions. I posted a screenshot of my Render Layers Properties. My questions is different due to the fact that I mention the version of Blender in which it doesn't work, and the manual for the same version showing that it should be there. but I just don't manage to figure out how. Besides, that post is 1 year old, and noone will look into to try to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Got it solved, thanks to this video by Blender Nerd ( Thanks ).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ItWP3lGBGY

Basically you need to first enable / activate "Freestyle" in the Properties > Render Tab.

Then you can go to the Properties > Render Layers Tab and you'll see a new section called: Freestyle